# Subcategories and resource controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Im using a resource controller to  control articles.

```
/news
```

Hits the index method and brings up all the articles under the category.

```
/news/article-slug
```

Hits the show method and brings up an article under the category.

My question involves sub categories.

```
/news/sub-category-name
```

This would hit the show method which would look for an article with the sub-category-name when I want it to hit the index method and bring up a list of articles for the sub category.

What would be the approach to use for sub categories?

Add another route and method like:

```
get('/news/{subcategory}', [
    'as'=>'subcategory',
    'uses'=>'ArticleController@getSubCategory',
]);
```

Or would it be better practice to scrap sub categories and have a url like:

```
/news-sub-category-name/article-slug
```

Or is there another way?

Comment: it's too opinion based...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking semantics you would be better to servers category names then the title. ie

```
www.domain.com/news/category/article
```

This will also give you a clean approach for your routes file. IE no wildcard matching or regex to replace (cat-) etc.

Thats the way I would personally go.

It use to be in the past you would want to keep your URL's as short as possible but thats just not the case these days. Dont get me wrong thats not to say you want domain/cat/cat/cat.....

... Update

To use resources you would have something like.

```
Route::resource('news/{cat}/article', 'ArticleController');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Much appreciated. Any thoughts on the implementation side with resource controllers?